# If i send multiple messages to the same webworker, does it queue them up and process them sequentially?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

As the title says...

Basically, if I have a single webworker and post it 1000 messages at once.

Each message results in the worker performing a processing intensive operation.

Am I best to post each message to the webworker sequentially after the previous one completes, or can I safely send all the requests over to the worker knowing that they will just be processed and returned one by one as they complete?

If I do this am I better off implementing a queueing system within the worker? or is it not necessary?

I understand that this single worker is only a single thread and therefore the javascript operations will indeed occur synchronously within the webworker itself, but I am concerned about contention in a similar way that performing 200 ajax requests at once would overwhelm a browser.

I hope this makes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The worker will queue up messages (specifically, it will queue up calls to `onmessage`) and process each message when ever the worker's call stack is empty.

This means, however, that asynchronous operation could result in input multiple messages being processed before any any particular operation is completed. For example:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/" + e.data);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        postMessage(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

If you passed in 1000 messages at once, I suspect the browser will fire off 1000 Ajax requests (or at least a lot of requests) before it runs `postMessage` inside of `onload`. This is because `onload` does not run until the Ajax call is complete, and each `onload` call will be added to the event queue behind any pending calls to `onmessage` that were requested before the Ajax fetch could complete.

If you wanted to ensure that only one Ajax request is out at a time, you could indeed implement an internal queue that moved only when `onload` was called:

```
var queue = [];
var busy = false;

onmessage = function(e) {
    if(busy) {
        queue.push(e);
    }
    else {
        busy = true;
        runAjax(e);
    }
}

var runAjax = function(e) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", e.data);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        postMessage(xhr.responseText);
        if(queue.length) {
            // run the next queued item
            runAjax(queue.shift());
        } else {
            busy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the first messages goes into the `else` block, which sets `busy = true` and runs the Ajax fetch. The following 999 messages are routed to the `if` block, because `busy` is `true` (and will not become `false` until the Ajax request completed *and* `queue` is empty). The queued messages are handled only after an Ajax request is complete.

If you wanted to tolerate more than one Ajax request at the time, you could use a counter instead of boolean: use `busy++` and `busy--` instead of setting `true` and `false`, and test that the current number of outstanding connections has not reached your allowed max (i.e., `if(busy == 5)` instead of `if(busy)`).

Answer (score 1):

The Web Worker receives each message one at a time - any queuing would be done by your own logic - for speed its best to transfer data as typed arrays especially a form called Transferable Objects - possibly you could put many (1000) messages into such a typed array (float or int) and make it a single message - the actual data transfer from browser to Web Worker or vice versa is quite fast - typed array of 10's of mbyte in milliseconds or less ... this messaging does handle objects as well albeit with a speed penalty compared to low level typed arrays